# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: list, if-statement, while-loop, int, typeerror

So basically I have to tell the user if the staff working in a phone shop has earned a bonus. If the staff sold 4 or more phones, they get a bonus.

Problem is I keep getting this error.

```
    if  list[member_number]>=4:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

This is my code-

```
How_Many_Members= int(input("Enter the number of staff members:"))

list=[]
member=1

while len(list)!= How_Many_Members:

    print("how many phones did the member", member,"sold?",end=" ")

    Sales=int(input(""))
    list.append(Sales)
    member=member+1


member_number=0

for list in range(0,How_Many_Members,1):
    if  list[member_number]>=4:
        print("member",member_number,"has earned a bonus")
        member_number=member_number+1
    else:
        print("member",member_number,"has not earned a bonus")
        member_number=member_number+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `list` objects. One is an array, and the other is an object in a for statement, here:

```
for list in range(0,How_Many_Members,1):
```

You are using duplicates, and that's not good and is the thing causing your program to spit the error. It is using that `list` instead of the array `list`. And since the `list` in the for loop is an integer object, the error is thrown. You are basically trying to use subscript on an array but it mistakes it as the integer from the for loop because it is ambiguous. Try the following:

```
How_Many_Members = int(input("Enter the number of staff members:"))

list = []
member = 1

while len(list) != How_Many_Members:
    print("how many phones did the member", member, "sold?", end=" ")

    Sales = int(input(""))
    list.append(Sales)
    member += 1

member_number = 0

for _ in range(0, How_Many_Members, 1):
    if list[member_number] >= 4:
        print("member", member_number + 1, "has earned a bonus")
        member_number += 1
    else:
        print("member", member_number + 1, "has not earned a bonus")
        member_number += 1
```

Something else, you misspelled `member_number` in a few places and I fixed that for you. I also shorted some statements and let it print `member 1` instead of `member 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
for list in range(0,How_Many_Members,1):
    if  list[member_number]>=4:
        print("member",memeber_number,"has earned a bonus")
        member_number=member_number+1
    else:
        print("member",memeber_number,"has not earned a bonus")
        member_number=member_number+1
```

You are saying for list in range(0, How_Many_Members), so list is taking an integer value from 0 to How_Many_Members-1. So it's not a list anymore and you can't do list[member_number].